# how to allow only a single marker

Tags: javascript, here-api

my map event listener adds a marker on click

```
 let coordsData = new H.geo.Point(coord.lat, coord.lng);
        let standardMarker = new H.map.Marker(coordsData);

        map.addObject(standardMarker);
```

how to make it if the user clicks again  to replace this marker with new one?
map.removeObjects()  and map.removeObject() both gives and error

like `map.removeObject(standardMarker)  map.addObject(standardMarker);`

Answer (score 0):

To remove an object from the map, a call to the map object's method **removeObjects** is required.

Please find the sample code snippet that creates a series of H.map.Markers for each location found, and adds it to the map. However, adding the **removeObjects()** method removes the marker object on every search.

```js
function addLocationsToMap(locations) {
        map.removeObjects(map.getObjects())        //
        //  debugger
        var group = new H.map.Group(),
          position,
          i;

        // Add a marker for each location found
        for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i += 1) {
          let location = locations[i];
          marker = new H.map.Marker(location.position);
          marker.label = location.address.label;
          group.addObject(marker);
        }

        group.addEventListener('tap', function(evt) {
          map.setCenter(evt.target.getGeometry());
          openBubble(
            evt.target.getGeometry(), evt.target.label);
        }, false);

        // Add the locations group to the map
        map.addObject(group);
        map.setCenter(group.getBoundingBox().getCenter());
      }
```

You can refer to this complete example:
https://jsfiddle.net/raj0665/1ck3v9oh/18/